# Relation row insertion in DB (plugin)

Tags: plugin-development, database

this is my first question on StackExchange regarding CraftCMS.

Currently im working on a plugin that should insert a relation row (in db) regarding an entry and asset (image).

Is there a simple and easy way to insert a row in the DB with asset id, source id and field id?

Thanks in advance

Comment: I'm a co-worker of Gerritjan and I will try to explain the question some more. We have a channel projects and a channel ideas. A project has related ideas through a field of the type entry. On the front-end our visitors can suggest ideas through a form for that project.
An idea is a title, image and description. How can we save this form easily in Craft when submitted?

Comment: If you're looking for a form-building solution, check out http://straightupcraft.com/craft-plugins/sprout-forms

Answer (score 2):

If I'm understanding you correctly, what you're looking for is the [RelationsService's saveRelations()](https://github.com/pixelandtonic/Craft-Release/blob/master/app/services/RelationsService.php#L29) accessed via `craft()->relations->saveRelations()`.

You pass in your $fieldModel, $source ElementModel and an array of $targetIds that you want to created the relations to.

Comment: Brad thanks for your reply. The solution given by you is for more relations, i only need one relation insertion.