# Save a selected category for a user (using a plugin)

Tags: plugin-development, matrix, users, categories, relations

I have some categories, and with the use of a category field a user can select these from within his / her profile.

Which is shown in the image:

[image]

In my Twig template I can get the user selections out using the following code.

```
{% set property_prefs = craft.categories({
    relatedTo: { sourceElement: currentUser, field: "propertyPreference" },
    limit:     null
}) %}
```

But what I want to know is how can I programmatically save a user selection using the API from within my plugin.

Also, which table are these stored in?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had to do something similar to this in a plugin recently, [Inserting Relationship Into Entries Field - Plugin Not Saving Relation](https://craftcms.stackexchange.com/questions/9713/inserting-relationship-into-entries-field-with-plugin-not-saving-relation), I know it's users to an entry field but I would assume the methods are similar.

So you will need 3 things in order to save a users categories

**1. The `Craft\FieldModel` of the field which has the associations**

`$field = craft()->fields->getFieldByHandle('propertyPreference');`

**2. The source, in this case the matrix block that has the field**

`$source = craft()->matrix->getBlockById(<someId>);`

**3. An array of element id's you wish to relate to the field**

`$relations = $user->propertyPreference->ids();`

Once you have those you can edit the `$relations` array however you see fit and then simply save the relations back

`craft()->relations->saveRelations($field , $source, $relations);`

[You can find out more about the save relations function in the class reference](http://buildwithcraft.com/classreference/services/RelationsService#saveRelations-detail)

As for which table, I would assume they are in `craft_relations`